# How does django know how to find templates? (1.2x)

Tags: django

Running through the djangobook (ver 2). I had a little trouble with template loading; my relevant filestructure:

```
testSite/urls.py

testSite/books/views.py  
testSite/books/templates/

testSite/contact/views.py  
testSite/contact/templates/
```

When I set-up a view for the books chapter (chap. 5), I was able to create a url in urls.py, point it to a view function in testSite/books/views, but when I called the template from that view function, I did not have to specify a directory - django knew it was in testSite/books/templates.

I tried doing the same thing for the contact form chapter (chap. 7), but this time it would not load the template - I had to go back to settings.py and explicitly place testSite/contact/templates into TEMPLATE_DIRS:

```
# testSite/settings.py
# ....
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/chris/djcode/testSite/templates',
    '/home/chris/djcode/testSite/contact/templates',
)
```

So - is there an obvious explanation as to why I need to point django to the contact/templates folder, but not the books/templates folder?

(If not, I can post more code - trying to keep it short)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either did not add the contact application to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py OR you are trying to load the template from one application inside another application.  The TEMPLATE_DIRS is where to look if it doesn’t find the template inside the same application as the views are loading from.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because a [Template Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS) knows how to find it. The `app_directories` one will find the `templates` directory in each application.

`django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` will use the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.

`django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` will find the `templates` directory in your installed apps.

If the first loader in the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting can't find it, Django will ask the next to see if it can find it.

How are you telling your views which templates you're using?

Comment: The problem was I forgot to list contact under INSTALLED_APPS - I +1'ed for explaining how django actually uses the information in the INSTALLED_APPs to find the templates in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I expect your `books` app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but `contact` is not.